# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IFilteredProjectionTableProps':

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react functional component which goes like this

```
const Strategy: React.FC<IFilteredProjectionTableProps> = props => {
....
...
}
export default Strategy;
```

This FC is assigned to as the component property of a tab element in this way

```
interface ITabInfo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  component: ReactElement;
}

const tabs: ITabInfo[] = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Board', component: <Board/> },
  { id: 1, name: 'Manager', component: <Manager /> },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Strategy',
    component: <Strategy />
  },
  { id: 3, name: 'New', component: <Create /> }
];
```

This assignment of the FC to the reactelement is raising this error "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IFilteredProjectionTableProps': ......"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to pass the properties to `Strategy` as defined in `IFilteredProjectionTableProps`

Comment: What is IFilteredProjectionTableProps?